# BreadCrumb Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, breadcrumb

I have 4 level sites in my Sharepoint Map, (the parents are not clickable links). When I add my BreadCrumb, it brings me the parents as links so I can click but I don't have content on the default pages. What Should I do to put the breadCrumb not clickable?
[image: My BreadCrumb]

Comment: How do you create your breadcrumb ?

Comment: @Max I too am interested in that

Comment: @thanby there are - as far as i know - 3 possible ways. [Via JS](http://www.eliostruyf.com/transform-the-sharepoint-suite-bar-text-into-a-breadcrumb-via-powershell/), [Serverside](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/building-breadcrumbs-sharepoint-2010/) or by using the [standard (and hidden by default) breadcrumb](http://academy.bindtuning.com/lets-bring-the-breadcrumb-back-to-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: @Max thanks for the links. The last one is the only method I was familiar with and it doesn't get as detailed as the OP's picture. But about a year ago when I was searching for a way to do it, that was the only way.

Answer (score 3):

Unless there is a out of box feature already there am not aware of, you can add a [content editor webpart](http://blog.incworx.com/blog/sharepoint-administrators-blog/hide-recently-modified-from-the-quick-launch) to the page, and use [jQuery's off click](http://api.jquery.com/off/) function for the links you don't want to be clickable.

Comment: An inline `onclick="return false;"` will also do.

Comment: @Max, Why don't you post it as answer?

Comment: @AlexeyKrasheninnikov there are loads of answers for not clickable links plus I thought without the actual code my answer would not answer the question

Comment: @Max, Looks like it does for OP :)